# OneToMany queries in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having some trouble working out the best way to do queries with one to many relationships in Django. Best explained by an example:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Items can have multiple attributes. Lets say the attribute is specific to an item though so ManyToMany is not appropriate here. How would I find all items with an attribute with name=a1 but also have an attribute with name=a2?

Something like this:

```
a1_objects = Attribute.objects.filter(name="a1").values("item__id")
a2_objects = Attribute.objects.filter(name="a2").values("item__id")
#Take the intersection (does this method of taking an intersection work?)
ids_with_a1_and_a2 = [id for id in a1_objects if id in a2_objects]
#Get item objects with those ids
results = Item.objects.filter(id__in = ids_with_a1_and_a2)
```

Surely there is a better way than my suggested approach? It doesn't seem efficient to me.

Comment: Your results will __always__ be an empty queryset. Do you mean to say get all the attribute names with item name `a1` and `a2` ?

Comment: Heh.  I first read the title as "One too many queries in Django."  It's better not to have so many queries!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this section in the docs: [Spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Unless I miss something, filtering `Item` should work:

```
Item.objects.filter(attribute_name="a1").filter(attribute__name="a2")
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise you could span relationships in both directions. Need a double underscore in attribute__name but otherwise working perfectly.

Comment: Good catch, just added the missing underscore. Glad you could figure it out anyway!